# In NTFS, what is the difference between the FRN and the FileID64?

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, ntfs, ntfs-mft

NTFS seems to have two internal identifiers for file system entries: the FRN (File Reference Number), and the FileID64.

From all the research I've been doing (aside from peering into actual code), they appear to serve the same function of identifying a file across the file system (i.e. the equivalent of `inode`s on Linux file systems).

What are the differences between them? And which one is more equivalent to inodes?

Comment: which windows structures/api you mean ? in general exist [`FILE_INTERNAL_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_internal_information) - *8-byte file reference number for a file* - this you mean under `FileID64` ? [`USN_RECORD_V2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-usn_record_v2) - *FileReferenceNumber* this you mean under `FRN` ? this both the same value and consist from 48 bit file index in MFT and 16 bit reuse index of record